# How to run bin/webpack with capistrano and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, capistrano

So I have a rails 6 app that doesn't load any css or javascript assets when I run `cap production deploy`.

So what I do is after I run `cap production deploy`, I ssh into my server, navigate to `myapp/current/` and run `bin/webpack` and then everything works. So I'd like my deployment process to do this for me so that I don't have to go into my server and run this everytime.

I've looked on how to run custom capistrano "tasks," but all the tutorials show you only how to run custom ***rake*** tasks, but this isn't a rake task.

I don't run `rake bin/webpack`, i just run `bin/webpack`.

So how I would go about implementing this in my capistrano setup? I assume I have to enter some sort of capistrano command in my deploy.rb.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of running the webpack binary on the server, you might be able to run it as a rake task by doing something like `rake webpacker:compile`. Then if that works you should be able to write a capistrano task that does the same think during deployment.

Comment: @DanielRistic yeah, that command didn't work. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 2):

Capistrano at its core is just ssh. It's doing something similar to what you're doing when you ssh (although slightly different because it's not typically an interactive session).

You could write a [custom task](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/tasks/) to run Webpack.

To do that you need to load them first if they're not already being loaded.
Check for this line in your `Capfile` or add it yourself. This will load your custom tasks which come in the form of rake tasks:

```rb
# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Then, create a task in that folder. Call it something like `lib/capistrano/tasks/webpack.rake`

```rb
namespace :webpack do
  task :build do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        # https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#the-command-map
        with path: "#{release_path}/bin:$PATH" do
          execute :webpack
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, you need to tell Capistrano when to execute it. I usually do this with `before/after` hooks. For more info check out [Capistrano flow](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/flow/)

after the namespace block add:

```rb
# lib/capistrano/tasks/webpack.rake
# ...
after "deploy:updated", "webpack:build"
```

you can test out task execution with `bundle exec cap production deploy --dry-run`